# There is vibration in car (2008 Honda CR-V). Getting new tires did not solve the problem

Tags: vibration, cv-joint, wheel-bearing

I bought a car (2008 Honda CR-V w/ 90k miles) that had a medium amount of vibration in the car (the vibrations are usually felt in the steering wheel as well). The tires that were on it were worn and out of balance and I thought that getting new tires would solve the vibrations.

I got new tires, and the vibration is still there. I think I narrowed the problem down to the CV joints, but I want to see if everyone agrees. The car starts vibrating around 50 mph and it gets worse the faster you go. The steering wheel vibrates back and forth very bad at 70+.  I noticed that when I had the car in cruise at 75 and let off the gas, the vibration would mostly go away which is why I am thinking the CV joints. There is no squeaking, and the vibration will intermittently stop for 30 seconds every once in a while, so I ruled the wheel bearings out. I also pushed and pulled the top and bottom of the tire and did not feel any loose play which leads me to believe the wheel bearings are fine. I pushed and pulled the sides of the tires to feel for loose play on the tie rods, but I don't think I felt anything (it was hard to distinguish loose play from moving the steering wheel back and forth). I know there are a few other things that could cause the problem, but I can't imagine the the other ball joints could cause this much vibrations.

There is not an obvious tear or leak on the boots of the CV joints, but I noticed the inner joint boots were much more greasy than the outer joint boots (this may have been cause by other oils in the engine).

Recap, the vibration is felt in the entire car, and it is the worst on the steering wheel (back and forth vibration). It is usually while "cruising" at higher speeds or accelerating to that speed.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

My father had the exact same problem that you describe on his 2007 Honda CR-V and it turned out to be a drive shaft.  Apparently they fail quite regularly on this model.  Replacing the shaft resolved the issue.

Comment: The 2008 CR-V has a carrier bearing in middle of the drive line. This is a prime location for the vibration to come from. It looks as though driveline replacement is the only way you can do it, as the carrier bearing does not appear for purchase separately. Your answer is spot on!

Comment: Steve, Thank you for the helpful response.

Pauster2 - The driveline and CV shaft is synonymous, correct?

Comment: sometimes driveshaft shops can replace these. fleetpride does this in my area maybe call around and see. the cv axles are what goto the hubs. the driveshaft goes to the rear differential.